# Cannot load resource api vue.js

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

Im having a problem load an backend api from my vuejs api.

It shows the following error

> > Access to XMLHttpRequest at Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/candidatos' from origin
> > 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> > 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> > resource.

Im trying to follow this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEyTBEyeHl4&list=PLWd_VnthxxLeRdaga093nbR64dALpbPwI&index=4

But my front end page is broken.

Im launching my spring boot api in port 8080

This is my backend controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@Api(value="API REST Produtos")
public class CandidatoController {

    @Autowired
    private CandidatoRepository candidatoRepository;

    @ApiOperation(value="Retorna uma lista de Candidatos")
    @GetMapping("/candidatos")
    public List<Candidato> listaCandidatos(){
        return candidatoRepository.findAll();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Retorna um Candidato unico")
    @GetMapping("/candidato/{id}")
    public Candidato listaCandidatoUnico(@PathVariable(value="id") long id){
        return candidatoRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Salva um Candidato")
    @PostMapping("/candidato")
    public Candidato salvaCandidato(@RequestBody @Valid Candidato Candidato) {
        return candidatoRepository.save(Candidato);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Deleta um Candidato")
    @DeleteMapping("/Candidato")
    public void deletaCandidato(@RequestBody @Valid Candidato Candidato) {
        candidatoRepository.delete(Candidato);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Atualiza um Candidato")
    @PutMapping("/Candidato")
    public Candidato atualizaCandidato(@RequestBody @Valid Candidato Candidato) {
        return candidatoRepository.save(Candidato);
    }

    //read json file to database
    public Iterable<Candidato> saveList(List<Candidato> candidatoList){
      return  candidatoRepository.saveAll(candidatoList);
    }
}
```

im loading the back end api from config.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api'
})
```

candidatos.js:

```
import {http} from './config'

export default {
    listar:()=>{
        return http.get('candidatos')
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You have allowed cors origin on `/api` urls but the error says your `/swagger-ui/*` has it still blocked. So you need to allow it for that also.

Comment: But hey your api call from vuejs to spring boot is wrong. Show us the vue js code for making the api call. You are not doing it right. It must be `localhost:8080/api/candidatos`

Comment: i changed again to 'http://localhost:8080/api' but the error persist

Comment: Your frontend server is loading at port :8081 and your backend on :8080, those are two different addresses and you are being blocked by CORS. Easiest way to solve this is to add a CORS header on your Spring backend that allows your frontend address (in this case localhost:8081).

Comment: He is using `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` which is allowing all though